# Are these axioms of real number strict？

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, axioms

After comparing with some other textbooks about introductory real analysis, I find that many books' content about axioms of real numbers are not strict (at least for me, I think they are not strict).
For example, in ross's $\textit{Elementary Analysis}$, the axioms he states are as follow:
[image]

and in bruckner's $\textit{Elementary Real Analysis}$, they state like this:
[image]

In both case, I find that they do not mention that $1$ should be assumed to not equal to $0$. My point is that we from these axioms, we can not argue that $1\neq0$, and also from these axioms, we can only conclude that there exists maybe two elements, $0$ and $1$. However, we can see that if we assume $0=1$, the set $R= \left\{ 0 \right\}$ with two operation $+: R \times R\to R,0+0=0$, $*:R \times R\to R, 0*0=0:$can also satisfy the field axioms, and furthermore, it can satisfy the order axioms.

So, I think they are not strict. Can anyone tell me if my arguments are right?

Addition: Thanks for @Henry remind me that in Ross's book, he adds in the late that the R should have at least two elements,so my construction doesn't work for this example. However, I don't know how to prove that $0 \neq 1$.

Comment: You are right, these axioms are not enough to define the real numbers. For example, the set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ also satisfy the axioms.

Comment: you also don't say anything about completeness, that any Cauchy sequence of rationals possesses a limit that is also a real number; furthermore, Cauuchy sequences of reals do not add any new points.

Comment: You haven't shown us all the axioms from either book, I think, so it's not easy to make a useful comment or answer. It is usual for the axioms for a ring not to require $0 \neq 1$, but that is a usual requirement for a field. The real numbers are a very special field, and I would be amazed if these books did not provide additional axioms (to do with the ordering and completeness, for example) to cover that.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose: the axioms quoted do not imply $0 \neq 1$.

Comment: @KentaS They do not claim to define the real numbers.  The Ross example calls these *field properties* during a discussion about $\mathbb Q$ and later introduces ordered fields and completeness

Comment: @Henry Yes, I agree. That was my point.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose uniqueness doesn't necessarily mean that $0\ne1$...?

Comment: The fact that the multiplicative unit is unique does not prevent it from being equal to zero. There is a unique structure for the language of rings that has exactly one element. It satisfies all the axioms for rings and also the axiom that every element has a multiplicative inverse. It is usual to exclude this in the axioms for a field by requiring $0 \neq 1$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose In the trivial ring there is a  single element which has the properties of $0$ and $1$ and since there are no other elements, it is uniquely unique.  I would say M4 in the quotations is also satisfied because they do not say "*Only* for $a \not =0$ ..." so it becomes a vacuous truth

Comment: @Henry: and, in fact, in the ring with one element, the existence of a multiplicative inverse for every $a$ holds, without requiring $a \neq 0$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I agree - which is why I pointed out that M4 did not say "Only"

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose If a set with only one elements, so the uniqueness is ordinary conditions.

Comment: After thought, yes I agree. Uniqueness definitely doesn't mean they can't be equal. My guess is that the author was trying to get across the fact $0$ and $1$ were different, but used sloppy language in the process

Comment: For a "good" axioms system, see [Tarski's axiomatization of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axiomatization_of_the_reals): it assumes the existence of $1$ and prove (from Ax.5) the existence of $0$.

Comment: In Tarski's system, from $\forall x (x=x+0)$ and $1 < 1+1$ we derive that $0 \ne 1$.

Comment: If instead we assume both $0$ and $1$, we have to add the axiom $0 \ne 1$

Comment: See for a good source: Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis (Springer, 2011)](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PA63)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd question for a simple reason: the set of axioms you've listed are a set of axioms that $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies, but they are not a set of defining axioms. Neither book you quote from pretends that these are a complete set of axioms defining $\mathbb{R}$.

Referring to Ross's book (which I have a copy of, and thus I can actually refer to) for example, you've copied exactly the set of axioms defining a (possibly trivial) field. In the next paragraph, Ross continues to define a *field* as a set with at least 2 elements satisfying the properties A1-A4, M1-M4, and DL. In the following paragraph, Ross gives an additional set of axioms that every *ordered field* must satisfy. Over the next couple of chapters, he describes how to construct the real numbers from the rational numbers (with an eye towards *completeness* and *Dedekind cuts*).

From this perspective, it should not be surprising that choosing a small subset of the properties that $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies doesn't uniquely distinguish $\mathbb{R}$. It might be an interesting exercise to try to come up with lots of structured sets that satisfy these axioms.

---

Let us now consider the question at the heart of your post. I rephrase it here.

> Suppose a set with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ satisfies the axioms A1-A4, M1-M4, and DL. Do these axioms on their own force $0 \neq 1$?

No, these axioms do not force $0 \neq 1$. The set consisting of the element $e$, defined with $e \cdot e = e$ and $e + e = e$ satisfies all of these axioms. You've noted this in your question.

---

Suppose that we include the next paragraph of Ross's book, which requires that a field have at least $2$ elements.

> Suppose a set $S$ with the binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ satisfies the axioms A1-A4, M1-M4, DL, and that in addition $S$ contains at least two elements. Does this force $0 \neq 1$?

Now the answer is yes. To see this, suppose that $0 = 1$. As $S$ contains at least $2$ elements, there is some other element $a \neq 0$.

Then we must have both that $a \cdot 1 = a$ and $a \cdot 0 = 0$, but as $0 = 1$ this forces $a = 0$. This is a contradiction.

(In this, I have assumed that $a \cdot 0 = 0$. You can prove this from the field axioms, and this is done in Theorem 3.1 of Ross for example).

Thus $1 \neq 0$.

---

This leads to a natural question.

> Suppose that a set $S$ has at least two elements and satisfies the axioms A1-A4, M1-M4, and DL. Does this force $S$ to be the real numbers?

No! The set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies these properties. (Indeed, this is the center of the narrative in Ross at this point). But there are lots of other structures too.

For example, consider $S$ to be the numbers $0, 1, 2$, and consider the binary operator $+$ to be *addition modulo $3$* the binary operator $\cdot$ to be *multiplication modulo $3$*. This is a set of $3$ numbers, and this is also a field. The non-obvious thing here is that $2^{-1} = 2$, as $2 \cdot 2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$.

---

This line of thinking, where you try to determine a set of axioms that specifies $\mathbb{R}$, is a very healthy line of thinking. This is not so trivial!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer makes me clearer about these axioms.